# Installed Kiln on Debian Linux with sudo gdebi kiln_0.5.1_amd64.deb , but the UI won't open in the browser. What can I do?

Tags: kiln

Kiln seems to be installed and enabled. At least that's what systemctl list-unit-files --type=service | grep kiln suggests, which shows "kiln.service                               enabled". I have rebooted several times, but typing http://localhost:8000 in Firefox always tells me "Unable to connect". What could be the cause of this?
Ubuntu is based on Debian, so the .deb file should work. I first tried installing it via dpkg, but that failed. I think it was a dependencies issue, since using gdebi seemed to solved the issue. Could it be, that I still need to hand-install some Ubuntu specific stuff for it to run in my browser?

Comment: Have you tried `http://127.0.0.1:8000` in case your loopback is not enabled? Also, is the systemd service showing that it's active and running without error? You can also look at logs with `journalctl -u kiln -ef`

Comment: -- Logs begin at Fri 2019-04-19 10:22:48 CEST. --
Apr 19 23:15:14 user systemd[1]: kiln.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 19 23:15:14 user systemd[1]: kiln.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 19 23:15:19 user systemd[1]: kiln.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.

Comment: Apr 19 23:15:19 user systemd[1]: Stopped Kiln.
Apr 19 23:15:19 user systemd[1]: Started Kiln.
Apr 19 23:15:19 user run-kiln[19660]: unshare: unshare failed: Operation not permitted
Apr 19 23:15:19 user systemd[1]: kiln.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE  over and over again

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I am using Debian. Isn't Ubuntu just a repackage of Debian? Fredcy recommends using Debian...

Comment: I'm sorry. I see that in the title now.

Answer (score 2):

Version 0.5.1 of Kiln has a Debian package (.deb) that, ironically, doesn't work on Debian. It only works on Ubuntu. This is because Ubuntu enables user namespaces by default but Debian does not. You can manually enable them on Debian by following the "permanent" instructions here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303214/197651

```
echo 'kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1' > /etc/sysctl.d/userns.conf
```

This should be fixed in an upcoming release by having the installer do this step for you.

Comment: Great! This worked. You are amazing! Thank you so much.

Comment: Just noticed, that the node has grown bigger than what I can download locally :-( So, "bonus" question, I guess: how do I configure Kiln to use a directory on my external storage medium, which is a 400 GB SSD drive?

Comment: You need to pass `--kiln-data-dir=/path/to/another/place` to Kiln. For the deb package you can configure custom arguments by following instructions here: https://gitlab.com/obsidian.systems/tezos-bake-monitor/blob/develop/docs/distros/ubuntu.md#configuring-the-ubuntu-package

So, e.g. you'd `echo 'KILNARGS="--kiln-data-dir=/path/to/location"' > /etc/kiln/args`

Comment: You will also, of course, need to move the old data directory to this new location if you want to reuse it. If you actually ran out of disk space then your node might be stuck on invalid blocks (which requires some manual intervention) so it might be easier to just start from scratch.

Comment: Thanks! I stopped and removed the old node, changed the args, restarted kiln, created a new node and then stopped it again after this this happened https://i.imgur.com/w4vcSIy.png: no data is showing up in the Kiln Data folder.

Comment: @ciTEZen Easiest way: Remove spaces from your folder name (and parents). Otherwise, you need to add quotes around the path itself like `KILNARGS="--kiln-data-dir='/path/to/folder with space'"`. You will need to also `sudo systemctl restart kiln` after changing the config. I neglected to mention that part before.

Comment: Unfortunately this option will not work with debian installation (as of kiln 0.5.1), because the kiln has access to only some areas of the filesystem.

As a workaround you can mount your external disk on the path `/var/lib/kiln/data-dir`